# Magento 2 InsertForm component in to the UI form component not show form buttons

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, magento2.4.6, modal-popup

I added form to admin modal with InsertForm UI component based on documentation. https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/insert-form/

Unfortunately this not show the form buttons. If I change the InsertForm component's renderUrl param to mui/index/render_handle as writes the documentation, the form not show.

**Vendor\OrderMap\view\adminhtml\ui_component\order_map_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">order_map_form.order_map_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">order_map_form.order_map_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create invoice</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">order_map_form</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="order_map_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="order_map/order/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\OrderMap\Model\DataProvider" name="order_map_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>order_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>order_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

        <button name="modal_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">order-map-button</item>
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Open modal</item>
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.timing_modal.license_plate_number_form_loader</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">destroyInserted</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.timing_modal</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">openModal</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName}.timing_modal.license_plate_number_form_loader</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">render</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </button>
    <modal name="timing_modal">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery timing</item>
<!--                    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">-->
<!--                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">-->
<!--                            <item name="text" xsi:type="string">Save</item>-->
<!--                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-primary</item>-->
<!--                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">-->
<!--                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">-->
<!--                                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">index = license_plate_number_form</item>-->
<!--                                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">save</item>-->
<!--                                </item>-->
<!--                            </item>-->
<!--                        </item>-->
<!--                    </item>-->
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <insertForm name="license_plate_number_form_loader">
            <settings>
                <formSubmitType>ajax</formSubmitType>
                <renderUrl path="mui/index/render">
                    <param name="handle">license_plate_number_form</param>
                    <param name="buttons">1</param>
                </renderUrl>

                <toolbarContainer>${ $.parentName }</toolbarContainer>
                <ns>license_plate_number_form</ns>
                <externalProvider>${ $.ns }.license_plate_number_form_data_source</externalProvider>
                <exports>
                    <link name="order_id">${ $.externalProvider }:data.order_id</link>
                </exports>
                <imports>
                    <link name="order_id">${ $.provider }:data.order_id</link>
                </imports>
            </settings>
        </insertForm>
        <field name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </modal>
</form>
```

**Vendor\OrderMap\view\adminhtml\ui_component\license_plate_number_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">license_plate_number_form.license_plate_number_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign delivery time</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign delivery time</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <namespace>license_plate_number_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>license_plate_number_form.license_plate_number_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>

    <dataSource name="license_plate_number_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="order_map/order/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\OrderMap\Model\DataProvider" name="license_plate_number_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>order_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>order_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="license" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">License plate number</label>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="Vendor\OrderMap\Model\Source\LicensePlateNumber"/>
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>

        <field name="to_date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">hh:mm</item>
                        <item name="minDate" xsi:type="string">new Date()</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Shipping date</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>to_date</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I uncommented the modal buttons option the modal button is show but after rendered the form the actions section show double.

[image]

Magento version is 2.4.6-p2

Anybody can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `mui/index/render_handle`, which you absolutely should be using, otherwise you won't have access to your buttons, the `handle` param is not the same as the inserted form's name. That param should reference a layout file, even if that layout file isn't used for rendering the form otherwise.

In your case, you need to have a layout file like this:
`Vendor\OrderMap\view\adminhtml\layout\license_plate_number_form_page.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="license_plate_number_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Only then will this work:

```
        <insertForm name="license_plate_number_form">
            <settings>
                <renderUrl path="mui/index/render_handle">
                    <param name="handle">license_plate_number_form_page</param>
                    <param name="buttons">1</param>
                </renderUrl>
            </settings>
        </insertForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

With default `render_url(mui/index/render)` form will be without form buttons. To get Form with buttons, url must be changed to `mui/index/render_handle` and next GET parameters:
`buttons=1`, so replace:

```
<renderUrl path="mui/index/render">
                    <param name="handle">license_plate_number_form</param>
                    <param name="buttons">1</param>
                </renderUrl>
```

with

```
 <renderUrl path="mui/index/render_url">
                <param name="handle">license_plate_number_form</param>
                <param name="buttons">1</param>
            </renderUrl>
```

and that should resolve it. Refer to `render_url` section here:  https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/insert-form/#options and